# How does the Facebook "create-react-app" differ from "dotnet new react"? Is development and maintenance the same?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, asp.net-core-3.0, asp-net-core-spa-services

I'm starting my exposure to React from a .Net Core perspective. From a beginner perspective it seems that in addition to the Kestrel and IIS servers exposed in .NET Core, there is another thing that listens on HTTP, which is geared towards real time React development... especially with Redux.

What are the notable differences between the two ways of starting a project?

.. in development,

.. in debugging, (e.g. ASPNETCORE=Development seems to enable special things)

.. in runtime?

What's new/different in Core 3.0 now that many server side execution operations have been removed?

Answer (score 1):

I can answer part of this.  create-react-app is written by the facebook team and gives you a nice way to build a react app without having to learn webpack and all the dependency management typically associate with creating a spa.  Great way to start but a big downside is it does not support server-side rendering which might be important to you.

`dotnet new react` is the cli command that scaffolds an asp.net core web project that essentially scaffolds both the asp.net core web app/project as well as the create-react-app project.  When you ultimately deploy your react app build with this template, the static files created are deployed from the asp.net core server.

When debugging, it's basically the same regardless of which you use.  create-react-app is agnostic about where you deploy the files that you get when you run "npm build". You could deploy those from any web server.